# Thread.sleep(#milliseconds) is working locally. When deployed to heroku, the program doesn't pause

Tags: java, heroku, bots, twitter4j

I'm doing calls to twitter from my twitter bot. Twitter has a limit of 180 calls per hour I believe, so I have a sleep function between calls so that I can keep it below that amount every hour. It works flawlessly on my machine, but does not pause when I'm watching the logs on Heroku.

The program has some functions and then here is the sleep function.

```
Thread.sleep(90000);
```

I'd like to wait 90 seconds between calls: 1) to limit calls, 2) to make it tweet less often. The program actually does seem to pause 5000ms, which is what I used to have it set on. I made a new local folder and cloned the repo to it to make sure that the repo didn't still have the old parameter of 5000 for the sleep function, but it said 90000 as it should. Is there any particular reason this wouldn't work on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The .jar file was not updating with the new code. Once I deleted and remade the jar file, everything worked as intended.